# Printing to main window while a form is active in foxpro

Tags: visual-foxpro

I'm wondering if it is possible to output text to the main window in foxpro while a form is active? Once the form is up my ? commands get sent to the form but that is not where I want them displayed.

Comment: The ? is an old purpose for output... what are you trying to actually do/generate/report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the [AllowOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa976881%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) property of your form to false.

> Setting the AllowOutput property to False (.F.) on a form, changes the following Visual FoxPro behavior.
>
> - Painting of the form is redirected to the next output window or desktop. This affects commands, such as ?, ??, DIR, LIST, DISPLAY, CLEAR, and other commands that display output on a form.
> - The WOUTPUT( ) function does not return the name of the active form. It returns the name of the current output form or desktop.
> - The BROWSE command does not inherit the window size and window settings of the form.
> - The MCOL( ) and MROW( ) functions, without the use of their optional parameter, may not be relative to the form they are called on.

Answer (score 3):

Look into the command

ACTIVATE SCREEN

This should redirect to the main VFP window and not the window you are currently in.  I know, it's a pain with these '?' outputs that keep shifting up the visual content within whatever is the current window.